# Problem with my thumbnails in gallery

Tags: gallery, samsung-galaxy-5, thumbnails

I have a problem with images in my gallery. The thumbnails of my photos are not the actual images when I view the image. The thumbnails are the photos which I have deleted or my other images in my phone. What might be the problem why the thumbnails are not the actual images? Is it messing with my caches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A comparable issue happened to me twice. The first time my audio files database was empty after a synchronization that went wrong. The second time my pictures application was never able to load the thumbnails. Each time the solution has been the same: clear the multimedia database.

To do so, go in "Settings" -> "Applications" -> "Manage applications". Then make sure you set the filter to see all applications. Find "Media Storage" in the list and then press "clear data". After that, you will need to wait a little bit for the database to regenerate, you may even have to reboot the phone to trigger the database generation.

This should correct your issue, and many more issues related to the multimedia database under Android.

Comment: That should fix it.  I think it's probably due to TouchWiz is this case though.  I've noticed thumnails don't change when you edit photos sometimes.

Comment: i haven;t seen a multimedia storage in my applications. i have filtered it to see all applications. but there is no multimedia storage. there is a media storage. i've tried to clear data of it and restart my phone but it didn;t fix my problem.

Comment: Media Storage is the one I was talking about, sorry for the confusion. If it didn't solve your problem I can't see what else you could do. Maybe try again and make sure you let some time for the phone to rebuild its media database after you reboot the phone.

Comment: After folwing top settings my all pictures are deleated.so dont try it

Answer (score 0):

Download android photo recovery on PC  & launch it.
Connect android device with USB  & click start.
Check box in-front of gallery & click next.
Select "deleted thumbnail".& click "recover"