# Why is it that the thumbnails of my images in gallery are not the same with the actual image?

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with my thumbnails in gallery.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/problem-with-my-thumbnails-in-gallery)

Why is it that the thumbnails of my images in gallery are not the same with the actual image? The images that I deleted was the thumbnail of the images now. Need some help here. Please

Comment: I replied to a very similar question at http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5471/2433

Comment: Is there a way to merge this question with a similar one or only the moderators can do it?

Comment: @jmb yes, people with at least 3000 rep can vote to close a question as a duplicate of another. If you haven't got 3000 rep yet, you can use the "flag" link to let a mod know.