# How can I prevent the Google+ app from showing the wrong thumbnail before I share a photo?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gallery, google-plus, thumbnails

When I go to the Google+ app to share a picture I've taken on my phone, it shows the wrong thumbnail.  I select the thumbnail anyway because experience has taught me that I can trust the date, and I when I share the picture the correct picture is shared.  This is incredibly frustrating, however, as I'm effectively "flying blind" when I share photos with the Google+ app.

I've developed various coping mechanisms for dealing with this problem.  I go into the Gallery app and delete all but pictures I want to share on Google+ and count the number of pictures I want to share.  Then I select the first few pictures (say, four) and share them on Google+.  Even though the thumbnails are wrong because I've already done the legwork to know which picture is which.

I've sent feedback to Google about this multiple times (it bothers me that there is no public record of this) and have been updating the Google+ app regularly, but the problem persists.  As of this writing I'm using version 2.3.0.240337 of the Google+ app on Android 2.2.

I don't *think* this has anything to do with how I manage pictures on my Android phone, but I'll describe that anyway.  Every so often I put my phone in USB mode and import my photos into iPhoto.  Then (after safely ejecting the device), from the phone I do a "select all" and "delete all" of all the pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I *think* this might be helping, but it's an odd fix. . .

After reading [the answer to another question on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/5472/4339) I tried the following:

1. Settings | Applications | Manage Applications | All | Media Storage | Clear Data
2. rebooted phone
3. opened Gallery app (nothing there, but I should have seen one picture)
4. took a picture (now pictures started appearing in the Gallery app)

And now the Google+ app shows the correct thumbnail. . . for now at least.  This is a pretty serious kludge and not at all user-friendly.  I hope it helps someone.