# Karbonn A9 is not generating thumbnails

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gallery, thumbnails

My friend has bought a Karbonn A9 phone one month ago and it has a little problem now. It has 16GB memory card and it is not generating thumbnails in the stock gallery very well. If I open a folder to view the images it only generate thumbnails for 1-4 pictures and others are blank.

I tried [this solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/problem-with-my-thumbnails-in-gallery) without any luck. What can I do?

Comment: Have you considered using an alternative Gallery app like QuickPic? Far more options and faster as well.

Comment: @Sparx I know about the third party apps there are a lot of for this task but I'm trying to figure out why the stock gallery is not working correctly. After using the solution in the link I have mentioned in my post I'm able at least to generate most of the thumbnails but not completely yet. BTW Thanks for your response.

Comment: My logic at suggesting using another app was so it might help narrow the problem - is it the Android media scanner at fault or something with the images themselves etc.

Comment: Another possible solution - use a cache cleaner app like CacheMate to clean app caches and try again.

Comment: @Sparx already tried clean the cache by APP2SD app but still no luck with the stock gallery, and there is no problem with the images itself.